# React props are not passing for children... Why?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying make an "easy" weather app exercise, just get data from api and render it. I am using "google api map" to get the location from a post code to a latitude and longitud parameters so I can use those numbers and pass it to "open weather map" api to get the weather for that location.

It is working but with bugs...

First I used redux for "location" and "weather". Redux was working but useSelector() wasnt displaying the data properly.

Then I decide to make it easy, on "search" component I am calling an api an getting the location I need, I am storing it with redux and it is working, on "weatherFullDispaly" component I am calling an api for the "weather" details and just pass it as props for the children to render the data but they are not getting it.

**The thing is, while the app is running, when I put a post code I get an error because the children are not receiving the data but, if I comment out the children on the parent component and then comment in again, all the data print perfect.**

Any help please???

```
const WeatherFullDisplay = () => {
  const [weatherDetails, setWeatherDetails] = useState();

  const currentLocation = useSelector(getLocationData);

  useEffect(() => {
    getWeatherDetails();
  }, []);

  const getWeatherDetails = async () => {
    const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY;
    const { lat, lng } = await currentLocation.results[0].geometry.location;
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${lat}&lon=${lng}&exclude=minutely&units=metric&appid=${API_KEY}`
    );
    setWeatherDetails(response.data);
  };

  return (
      <div className="weather-full-display-details">
        <WeatherNow weatherDetails={weatherDetails} />
        <HourlyWeather weatherDetails={weatherDetails} />
        <FiveDaysWeather weatherDetails={weatherDetails} />
      </div>
  );
};
```

```
const FiveDaysWeather = ({ weatherDetails }) => {

  const displayDailyWeather = () => {
    const daysToShow = [
      weatherDetails.daily[1],
      weatherDetails.daily[2],
      weatherDetails.daily[3],
      weatherDetails.daily[4],
      weatherDetails.daily[5],
    ];
    return daysToShow.map((day, i) => {
      return (
        <WeatherSingleCard
          key={i}
          typeOfCard="daily"
          weekDay={moment(day.dt * 1000).format("dddd")}
          icon={day.weather[0].icon}
          weather={day.weather[0].main}
          temp={day.temp.day}
        />
      );
    });
  };

  return (
        <div className="day-single-cards">{displayDailyWeather()}</div>
  );
};
```

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  locationDetails: "",
};

const locationSlice = createSlice({
  name: "location",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setLocation: (state, action) => {
      state.locationDetails = action.payload;
    },
    cleanLocation: (state) => {
      state.locationDetails = ""
    }
  },
});

export const { setLocation, cleanLocation } = locationSlice.actions;

export const getLocationData = (state) => state.location.locationDetails;

export default locationSlice.reducer;
```

```
const SearchBar = () => {
  const [postCode, setPostCode] = useState();
  const [locationDetails, setLocationDetails] = useState();

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    getLocationDetails();
  }, [postCode]);

  const getLocationDetails = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json",
      {
        params: {
          components: `country:ES|postal_code:${postCode}`,
          region: "ES",
          key: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        },
      }
    );
    setLocationDetails(response.data);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(setLocation(locationDetails));
    navigate("/detail-weather");
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setPostCode(e.target.value);
  };
```

Comment: This *"if I comment out the children on the parent component and then comment in again, all the data print perfect."* doesn't sound right. Are you sure your watch is running correctly?

Comment: Thats my point, something is wrong, but i cant find out what...